# How to make user choose his own function

Tags: python

I am currently studying programming and I have the following problem.

A user should enter the operation that he wants to do from the command line and according to the operation, he should enter the information about the item.

I have tried things like the following:

```
def stock(f):
    d={}
    f()
    return d


def add(item,amount):
    d[item]=amount
    return d
```

Or

```
def stock(item,amount,f):
    d={}
    if f():
        d[item]=amount
    return d


def add():
    return True
```

and, second one doesn't work for me because, when i want to use this code remove(a,b) i don't need three argument. What i'm trying to say is number of argument changes according to my operations. How do i handle this.

Comment: Could you explain the bigger picture? What is the user meant to be able to pass as functions, is input from somewhere supposed to be supplied to those functions...

Comment: A user should enter the operation that he wants
to do from the command line and according to the operation, he should
enter the information about the item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need a dictionary factory pattern

```
>>> class Calc(object):
    def __init__(self):
            #Initialize a dictionary of keywords and callbacks
        self.operation = {
            'add':self.add,
            'sub':self.sub,
            'mul':self.mul,
            'div':self.div,
            'neg':self.neg

            }
    #Overload the function call
    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self.operation[args[0]](*args[1:])
    # *args - variable list argument list
    def add(self,*args):
        return sum(args)
    def sub(self,*args):
        return args[1] - args[0]
    def mul(self, *args):
        if len(args) == 0:
            return 1
        elif len(args) == 1:
            return args[0]
        else:
            return args[0] * args[1]
    def div(self, *args):
        return args[0] / args[1]
    def neg(self, *args):
        return -args[0]


>>> calc = Calc()
>>> calc('add',1,2,3)
6
>>> calc('mul',10)
10
>>> calc('mul',10,4)
40
>>> calc('neg',3)
-3
>>>
```

Comment: Is there any easy way to do this i have no idea what is __init__ or self

Comment: Yes, place it outside a class. But without knowing your level of expertise, we cannot give any solution.

Comment: I think this is closest to what the OP wants: a dispatch-dict, but with non-bound methods, and possibly a simple lookup on `sys.argv[1]` for operation...

Comment: Okay, but how can i change the 'add':self.add to 'add':self.d[x]=y  -- i need operation of adding to a dictionary

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're going for here, but a common thing to see in python code is a function defined as:

```
def foo(*args):
    print(args)  #args is a tuple
    print(len(args))  #you can inspect it's length to see how foo should behave
```

You can then call this function like:

```
foo(1)
foo(1,2)
foo(1,2,3)
foo(1,2,3,"spam")
```

etc.

Comment: what do you mean by "*args"

Comment: @billwild -- Exactly that.  Try putting it into a script and running it.  As I said, I'm not sure if this is what you're going for, or if this is helpful ... (If it's not, I'll happily delete).  But, you should at least try this out -- You'll learn something new today either way :)

Comment: @billwild Can I ask What level of experience with Python do you have (and programming in general?)

Comment: None, we have learned until dictionary and this was an exercises in the class. However, i didn't attend and i'm trying to keep up